# Cannot resolve symbol 'GoogleApiClient'

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to upgrade my Google Play Services library so I can use the newest Android Gradle (3.2) and Android SDK version (28).  The issue is all of my GMS imports cannot be resolved.

Examples:

`import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;`

and

`import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;`

I've already looked at various questions that have issues with importing these libraries but none are up-to-date or appear to fix my issue.  I've tried invalidating cache/restart, clean/rebuild project.  Currently I am importing a `google-play-services_lib` library, which has the bundled GMS as a dependency: `com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1`

My project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}

compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.exampleapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 34         // increment with every release
    versionName '3.0.5'   // change with every release
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "example_$versionName")
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias = "example key alias"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':google-play-services_lib')
    implementation project(':appcompat_v7')
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
```

My module/app build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jCenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
           url 'https://maven.google.com/'
           name 'Google'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

Hopefully there is a way to resolve these import errors, which seems to be a disconnect between the gradle building of support libraries and the actual project itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  For a migration from way-way back (like target API <= 21), **get rid of using the bundle/manual library and stick with a newer Gradle version**:

1. Remove the meta tag from Android Manifest that specifies a Google Play Services version (the bundled version)
2. Remove your `google-play-services_lib`
3. Add the necessary GMS dependencies to the project-level `build.gradle`, whether manually or in File → Project Structure → MyApp Module → Dependencies tab and add library, even if it doesn't show in the new Android Studio's library search.

**Example:** `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'`

I know this was fairly obvious but this might be a good post for migrating somewhat-old Android apps that use GMS to newer versions.  This at least lets you pick which GMS modules to use rather than the bulky bundle.